# Creating multiple JOIN in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to create this query in laravel. This query helps to get the Total Bill of A Patient and Total amount already paid by that patient from different table
patient table : where the patient record is fetched
billings table : where patient billing is stored
payment table : where all payment made by patient is store

```
SELECT  A.id,A.name,SUM(B.totalInvoice) as totalAmount,SUM(C.totalPayed) 
as totalPayed
FROM     patients as A 
LEFT JOIN 
(
select  patient_id
    ,       sum(amount) as totalInvoice
    from    billings
    group by
            patient_id
    ) as B
ON      B.patient_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    select  patient_id
    ,       sum(amount) as totalPayed
    from    payments
    group by
            patient_id
    ) as C
ON      C.patient_id = A.id
```

how can this be created in laravel

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to create multiple join in laravel

```
DB::table('patients')->select(
                            'patients.id',
                            'patients.name as name',
                            \DB::raw('SUM(billings.amount) as totalAmount'),
                            \DB::raw('SUM(payments.amount) as totalPayed')
                            )
                            ->join('billings','billings.patient_id','=','patients.id')->groupBy('billings.patient_id')
                            ->join('payments','payments.patient_id','=','patients.id')->groupBy('payments.patient_id')
                            ->get()
```

Comment: still does not give the same result as the query